# How to create package alias in h2

Tags: java, package, h2, procedure

I am writing the test cases in java using h2 as in memory database.
and I need to create a package and inside it there is a procedure.

I am able to create a procedure using user defined funtions in h2 where I have create a java class and in it I have written the code to delete from a table.

Now, my code is calling this : 
PKG_ORCHESTRATOR.P_DEL_CONTROL_ORCHESTRATOR

I have written the user defined funtion for : P_DEL_CONTROL_ORCHESTRATOR

but since PKG_ORCHESTRATOR is not defined, I am getting error.

Could anyone please help me here.

Please let me know if I need to put more details.

Answer (score 1):

H2 doesn't have packages, but you can create a schema `PKG_ORCHESTRATOR` and define your alias in it.

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA PKG_ORCHESTRATOR;
CREATE ALIAS PKG_ORCHESTRATOR.P_DEL_CONTROL_ORCHESTRATOR FOR "full.class.Name.methodName";
CALL PKG_ORCHESTRATOR.P_DEL_CONTROL_ORCHESTRATOR(arguments);
```

If your procedure doesn't have arguments, you must write `()` after its name to invoke it anyway, otherwise it will not be recognized by the parser.

Comment: the package PKG_ORCHESTRATOR is already in another schema ( VR_OWNER). How can we do that ?

Comment: Once again, there is no such thing as package in H2 (and in the SQL Standard too). This is an Oracle-specific feature. You cannot create a package with H2, and it cannot be placed anywhere. If you're required to use something like `PKG_ORCHESTRATOR.P_DEL_CONTROL_ORCHESTRATOR(arguments)` to call the routine, just create a fake schema `PKG_ORCHESTRATOR` as described in my answer and use it instead of package to place your routine `P_DEL_CONTROL_ORCHESTRATOR` into it.